# how to send my precrowdsale funds to crowdsale contract?

Tags: contract-debugging

### I'm having a precrowdsale and a crowdsale, How can I send the ether from the first to the second once the precrowdsale is over? this is the script I have:

//send to crowdsale

```
if(receiver_address.send(amount_in_Wei)){
```

//sending is successful

} else {

// sending failed
}
}

---

but Ethereum Wallet compiler says:
 Could not compile source code.

Expected import directive or contract definition.
    if(receiver_address.send(amount_in_Wei)){
    ^

What's wrong? Thank you!!!!

Comment: You should consider improving the question. Add more code, please.

Comment: Also, it looks like, as it is, that the code is vulnerable to re-entrancy attacks.  http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/security-considerations.html

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [here](https://github.com/TokenMarketNet/ico/blob/master/contracts/PresaleFundCollector.sol), at the end of the file:

```
  /**
   * Set the target crowdsale where we will move presale funds when the crowdsale opens.
   */
  function setCrowdsale(Crowdsale _crowdsale) public onlyOwner {
     crowdsale = _crowdsale;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a code like this:

```
if (!wallet.send(msg.value)) {
    ...
}
```

and it compiles without errors. Are you using a pragma?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;
```

Try using it at the very first line of code.